# how to export Highchart to Power point

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm trying to export highchart to Power point, now i have the ability to export to ,but when i do for PPTX i have an error, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. This is my code

```
# Graph for Cumulative Probability Distribution  in pricing tab--Dynamic
  output$graphCumProbDistr_Dynamic <- renderHighchart({

    # Define export options
    export <- list(
      list(
        text = "PNG",
        onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/png' }); }")
      ),
      list(
        text = "JPEG",
        onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/jpeg' }); }")
      ),
      list(
        text = "SVG",
        onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'image/svg+xml' }); }")
      ),
      list(
        text = "PDF",
        onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'application/pdf' }); }")
      ),
      list(
        text = "PPTX",
        onclick = JS("function () {
                   this.exportChart({ type: 'application/pptx' }); }")
      )
    )

    Data_ <- Sim_table()


    hc_1 <- Data_ %>%
      hchart('scatter',
             hcaes(x = Index, y = Value),
             color = "#702080", borderColor = "#702080",
             name = "Index_Prob_Dist") %>% #pointWidth = 80,
      hc_title(text = "<b>Cumulative Probability Distribution of Index Values</b>") %>%
      hc_labels(Data_$Avg,"Index") %>%
      hc_exporting(
        enabled = TRUE,
        formAttributes = list(target = "_blank"),
        buttons = list(contextButton = list(
          text = "Export",
          theme = list(fill = "transparent"),
          menuItems = export
        ))
      )
    hc_1


  })
```

Do you know what i need to change to export to Power point?, Thanks !!

Comment: Are you sure that Highcharts can export PPTX?

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts does not support exporting to PowerPoint this way.

Comment: is there any way to export to pptx?